# Help with proof: if G is a group with neutral e, $g \in G$, $g^n = e$ and $g^{n/p} \neq e \forall$ prime $p$ such that $p|n$, then order of g is n

Tags: group-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

If $g^n = e$, I know that the order of g divides $n$. I suppose there exists $q \in \mathbb{Z}, q|n, q \neq n$, such that order of g is q. Then $g^q = e$.

Let $n = p_1p_2...p_k$. Then, for some $p_i$, $n/p_i = kq, k \in \mathbb{Z}$. For that $p_i$, $g^{n/p_i}=g^{kq}$, and as $g^q = e$, then $g^{kq}=g^{n/p_i} = e$.

And then by counter-reciprocal, if $g^{n/p} \neq e \forall$ prime $p$ such that $p|n$, then order of g is n.

The part of the proof I'm not sure about, is when I state that if $q|n$ and $n = p_1p_2...p_k$, then for some $p_i$, $n/p_i = kq, k \in \mathbb{Z}$. Is that statement true? If it is, how can I prove it?

Also, what's the notation for order of g?

Thanks!

Edit: my title looks all wrong, can someone help me with that? What did I do wrong there?

Comment: I agree that the statement you're asking about requires proof. Hint: show that you can choose $p_i$ to be any prime divisor of $n/q$.

Comment: Hint: if $g^n=e$ then you know the order *divides* $n$. Show that any proper divisor of $n$ is also a divisor of at least one number of the form $n/p$ with $p$ a prime that divides $n$.

Comment: By the way: your notation for $n$ suggests that you are assuming the primes are different. If you are going to invoke the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic, it might be better to write it in the usual form, $n=p_1^{a_1}\cdots p_r^{a_r}$, with $p_i\neq p_j$, all prime, and $a_i\gt 0$ for each $i$.

Comment: One thing that you did wrong was to write the complete question in the title. The question should be in the body of the post, and the title should provide an indication of  the topic of the question rather than complete details.

Comment: Thanks to all of you! So I gather that the proof is correct but I should definitely work on proving that one statement. I now understand why the statement is correct, so it will be easy enough.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin You are right, I actually mean that the pi can be equal, but it's not clear enough, and the other notation will help with that. I also realize now that I used the k for both the final index of the pi's and to say that n/pi = qk, but those are unrelated, so one of them should change. Thanks!

Comment: @DerekHolt Thanks for saying that! I'll keep that in mind for future questions. Cheers!